# Google Sheets alternating colors via API

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Using the sheets API with Python I'm attempting to format a sheet using alternating colors. In the UI this is found at Format > Alternating colors...

From what I've been able to find this is done via the API using [banding](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddBandingRequest). Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a working example of how this is done. Below is the values dictionary I've constructed, color values aren't important at the moment, I'd just like it to colorize the sheet.

```
requests = {
  'bandedRange': {
    'bandedRangeId': 1,
    'range': {
      'sheetId': 0,
      'startRowIndex': 0,
      'endRowIndex': len(values),
      'startColumnIndex': 0,
      'endColumnIndex': 4,
    },
    'rowProperties': {
      'headerColor': {
        'red': 1,
        'green': 0,
        'blue': 1,
        'alpha': 1,
      },
      'firstBandColor': {
        'red': 1,
        'green': 0,
        'blue': 0,
        'alpha': 0,
      },
      'secondBandColor': {
        'red': 0,
        'green': 1,
        'blue': 0,
        'alpha': 0,
      }
    },
  },
  'fields': '*',
}
body = {'requests': requests}
response = service.spreadsheets().batchUpdate(spreadsheetId=spreadsheet_id, body=body).execute()
```

This fails with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/oauth2client/_helpers.py", line 133, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 840, in execute
    raise HttpError(resp, content, uri=self.uri)
googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/$spreadsheet_id:batchUpdate?alt=json returned "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "banded_range" at 'requests': Cannot find field.">
```

I'm fairly certain my issue is the fields value, but I can't find a valid example of what to use here. I get the same error if I omit the fields key entirely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the reference docs for [batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate), `requests` takes an array of [Request](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request) objects.  Each `Request` must have exactly one field set, the available fields for banding being:

```
  "updateBanding": {
    object(UpdateBandingRequest)
  },
  "addBanding": {
    object(AddBandingRequest)
  },
  "deleteBanding": {
    object(DeleteBandingRequest)
  },
```

There is no field `bandedRange`, which is what you're trying to set.  That's what the error message (`Unknown name "banded_range" at 'requests': Cannot find field.`) is saying... though I have no idea why it translated bandedRange to snake_case.

Depending on if you want to add or update the banded range, you'd set either `updateBanding` with an [UpdateBandingRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateBandingRequest) object, or `addBanding` with an [AddBandingRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#AddBandingRequest) object.

By adding `addBanding` to your JSON format. As explained above you will end up creating the below JSON. Also, the key `fields` is optional.

```
  {'addBanding': {
      'bandedRange': {
        'bandedRangeId': 1,
        'range': {
           'sheetId': 0,
            'startRowIndex': 0,
            'endRowIndex': len(values),
            'startColumnIndex': 0,
            'endColumnIndex': 4,
        },
        'rowProperties': {
          'headerColor': {
            'red': 1,
            'green': 0,
            'blue': 1,
            'alpha': 1,
          },
          'firstBandColor': {
            'red': 1,
            'green': 0,
            'blue': 0,
            'alpha': 0,
          },
          'secondBandColor': {
            'red': 0,
            'green': 1,
            'blue': 0,
            'alpha': 0,
          }
        },
      },
    },
   },
```